# Remove value from a var

Tags: javascript, jquery, addition, var

I am having some problems removing parts of a var.

```
function hotBarClick() {
    var likeCount = 0;
    $.each(companies, function (key, value) {
        if (value.liked) {
            likeCount++;
        }
        if (value.liked && value.alreadyliked ==false) { 
            var content = value.getHtmlLogo(); 
             matchesHtml.add(content);
             this.alreadyliked = true;
        }
        if (value.liked == false && value.alreadyliked == true) {
            var discontent = value.getHtmlLogo();
            matchesHtml.remove(discontent);
            this.alreadyliked = false;
            }

    });
```

I am making a app based on html and javascript. You can like/dislike companies in the neighbourhood. If you liked 5 companies or touch the "hotbar" you will see a slider(owl-carousel) with the logos of the companies you liked.

My problem is that if you liked a company first and then dislike it, i cant remove the images from the slider, that were previously shown.
var matcheshtml is the var containing this infomation. You can see that in my code i add stuff by matcheshtml.add() but i cant seem to use the .remove() method here?

How do i remove the good part?

BTW: i think discontent contains the correct value

Comment: You'll have to provide more information to get an answer. For example: what does `getHtmlLogo()` do? And what _are_ the runtime values of the vars?

Comment: you'll need to provide a fiddle....